# Why is config.fish is loaded twice?

Tags: shell, fish

This is my config.fish:

> echo 'hello'

When I open a new terminal,'hello' is printed twice.I am using MintOS.

Comment: Brainstorm of things that might cause this: 1. the terminal emulator is duplicating the line after the prompt is drawn, or 2. you have configured your terminal emulator to run fish inside your shell (which is itself fish), or 3. the file sources itself or something else like that. Does it happen if you run fish from an existing terminal instead of opening a new one?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish Thanks.I use terminator and config fish inside.

Answer (score 0):

[The last time this happened](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2408), it was because fish starts a process in the background to update the generated manual page completions.

If you want to have fish print something out with interactive sessions, you should guard it with a `status --is-interactive` test:

```
if status --is-interactive
    echo hello
end
```